# How to detect edge points of an object using OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, oop

So, I have already detected all the edges of an object but the problem is that I can't find the two points of each edge, that is, the starting point and the ending point with its coordinates.

Actually I am trying to find the measurements of an object but I am stuck at this problem.[The image is regarding the ROI of the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdH5A.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

#Read Image of the Object
img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project\\captured.jpg")
cv2.imshow('Original Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)



#Convert Image To GrayScale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Gray', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)


#Binary Thresholding
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('Binary Image', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Crop Image
cropped = thresh[150:640, 150:500]
cv2.imshow('Cropped Image', cropped)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(cropped, 100, 200)
cv2.imshow('Edges', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#find contours
ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(cropped, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Sort Contours
sorted_ctrs = sorted(ctrs, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0] + cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[1] * cropped.shape[1])


#ROI
for i, ctr in enumerate(sorted_ctrs):
    # Get bounding box
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)

    # Getting ROI
    roi = cropped[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    # show ROI
    # cv2.imshow('segment no:'+str(i),roi)
    cv2.rectangle(cropped , (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (150, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('marked areas', cropped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24jXi.jpg)

[These are 5 points and the five edges that I need with coordinates so I can calculate the distance between them for the measurement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1YOh.jpg)

[Harris Corner Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szjFg.jpg)

Comment: Can you attach sample input image along with expected output ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the changes. Can you look at it now?

Comment: @JimitVaghela hii i have calculated the edge length of sides of image. Now, i want to know how to know represent it like https://imgur.com/a/e2CVGxA any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Harris Corner Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) instead:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_centroids(dst):
    ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst, 0.01 * dst.max(), 255, 0)
    dst = np.uint8(dst)

    # find centroids
    ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
    # define the criteria to stop and refine the corners
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 
                0.001)
    corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids),(5,5), 
              (-1,-1),criteria)
    return corners

image = cv2.imread("corner.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)

dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)

dst = cv2.dilate(dst, None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
# image[dst > 0.01*dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]

# Get coordinates
corners= find_centroids(dst)
# To draw the corners
for corner in corners:
    image[int(corner[1]), int(corner[0])] = [0, 0, 255]
cv2.imshow('dst', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image: Detected Corners]

You might need to fine tune the parameters for cornerHarris.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can I actually store these point values to a variable so I can use them to calculate the distance between them?

Comment: Yes you can. Just edited the answer. They are just close estimates to the found corners since it find multiple corners at the same corner

Comment: Also, the suggestion you have provided is giving me an error: 

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 330 but corresponding boolean dimension is 480

Comment: I have tried the code and it works. What error are you getting?

Comment: At line 32 : NameError: name 'corners' is not defined

I am having this error.

Comment: That is a pretty straight forward error. You should be able to fix it yourself. Try going through the code again

Comment: It worked! How to store the points that I am getting in a variable?

Comment: They are already saved in corners. If you want to save the new ones in _int_, do: `int_corners = np.asarray(corners, dtype=int)` If it worked, consider accepting the answer

Comment: Sorry to mention but the corners I am getting are different from what you showed in the output. Please check my output.

Comment: If you are using the same image as you uploaded, that isn't possible. I cropped the image you posted as _Original image_ to remove the window around the image

Comment: No, I used a cropped one as well. I am getting a different output. Check my output.

Comment: In that case, you need to fine tune the parameters for HarrisCorner. The process you should follow is exactly as I have mentioned in this answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Got the coordinates with print (corners). Accepted this as a solution.

Comment: @RickM. hii i have calculated the edge length of sides of image. Now, i want to know how to know represent it like https://imgur.com/a/e2CVGxAany idea how to achieve this